# How to reset a Material angular date range picker

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the Material date range selection in my Angular 11 project.
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-range-selection

I am trying to add a reset button like in this example for a date picker.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nv5qts

Please provide an example of this or explain how I can adapt it for the date range picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reset() {
    this.input.value = '';
}
```

You can see the reset method that sets the empty string for the date picker value.

You have already answered your question.

UPD:

Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the date range picker. You can use ngModel for inputs, here's an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jetzmj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-overview-example.html). Or [Angular Form](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jetzmj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-overview-example.html).

Comment: This does not work for date range picker because it does not use the MatInput property like the date picker does.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the date range picker. You can use ngModel for inputs, here's an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jetzmj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-overview-example.html). Or [Angular Form](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jetzmj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-overview-example.html).

Comment: If you update your answer I can mark it accepted.  Thank you!